# where is conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf on windows installation

Tags: neo4j

Sorry for the newbie question, i see lots of references to conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf , but cannot find this anywhere on my windows server installation of Neo4j 2.1.2.

can somebody tell me where it is please?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to create the "conf" directory yourself.

I tried it on my windows machine before answering you, as I encountered the same problem initially.

In my case, I first created the directory
C:\Program Files (x86)\Neo4j Community\conf
and in there I created the files

- neo4j.properties
- neo4j-wrapper.conf

See [Neo4j post here](http://www.neo4j.org/graphgist?d788e117129c3730a042)

Answer (score 0):

I might be mistaken, but, I don't believe the Windows version puts an instance of that file on disk.

Given that neo4j.properties is in your actual graph DB directory (e.g. c:\\Neo4j\default.graphdb), you might try creating an instance of the file there and seeing what happens.

Or you could also try creating a conf/ directory from that same location and putting it in there.

I'm used to working with the Linux version, myself.

Let us know what you find!

HTH

Comment: Thanks, will do, does editing neo4j.properties directly and restarting neo4j have any effect?

Comment: Yes definitely. The Neo4j docs have a list of properties in that file that can be changed. Any changes require a restart of Neo4j.