# increasing JVM memory and neo4j on win8.1

Tags: java, neo4j, jvm, jvm-arguments

I am running neo4j 2.1.7 on a windows 8.1 pro laptop. I have 16G of RAM, but I keep running out of heap memory. I have a large-ish database of maybe 250K nodes, but nothing close to what I am planning to run.

I have set -Xmx to 1024m in neo4j-community.vmoptions. I tried to increase it to more, but neo4j-community.exe won't start up.

Any advice would be gratefully received

Regards, Richard

Comment: what's the error you get when you start exe?

Comment: how are you setting max memory ? What is the error you see when you start `neo4j-community.exe` ?

Comment: The default maximum heap for a 64-bit JVM is 1/4 of main memory or 4GB, is there any reason you are decreasing it?

Comment: there is no error message produced, it just doesn't start up.

Comment: I want to set it to 4G, but it won't let me go past 1G. I have 10G of RAM sitting unused, very frustrating

Comment: I'm simply setting  -Xmx1024m in the vmoptions file

Comment: so `-Xmx4g` is vmoptions is not working for you ?

Comment: It says [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/configuration-jvm.html#_configuring_heap_size_and_gc), `When using Neo4j Server, JVM configuration goes into the conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf file`, so I think you need to set heap size like this `wrapper.java.additional=-Xmx4g`

Comment: In a windows installation I don't appear to have that file - or even a conf directory

Comment: Using -Xmx4g results in the error "The JVM could not be started. The maximum heap size (-Xmx) might be too large or an antivirus or firewall tool could be blocking execution".

Comment: That error means that when you try to run java process you don't have 4GB free memory at the time of starting JVM. When you say `-Xmx4g`, JVM process will ask the host OS for 4GB block and reserve it for future use. But you said you have 16gb ram, so check if there's any other process that's taking too much memory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71803/discussion-between-rick-it-2004-and-arkantos).

Comment: I just updated my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the official [docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/configuration-jvm.html#_configuring_heap_size_and_gc),

> When using Neo4j Server, JVM configuration goes into the
>   `conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf` file

So set the heap size like below in `neo4j-wrapper.conf` file,

```
wrapper.java.additional=-Xmx4g
```

On Windows, by default that folder and file won't exist.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179523/where-is-conf-neo4j-wrapper-conf-on-windows-installation) for a similar issue, you need to create that folder and that file insider your Neo4j installation directory.

You said that Using -Xmx4g results in the error `The JVM could not be started. The maximum heap size (-Xmx) might be too large or an antivirus or firewall tool could be blocking execution`.

That error means that when you try to run java process you don't have 4GB free memory at the time of starting JVM. When you say -Xmx4g, JVM process will ask the host OS for 4GB block and reserve it for future use. But as you already have 16gb ram, check if there's any other process that's taking too much memory.

Comment: In a windows installation I don't appear to have that file - or even a conf directory

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179523/where-is-conf-neo4j-wrapper-conf-on-windows-installation) for a similar issue, you need to create that folder and that file insider your Neo4j installation directory :)

Comment: you don't need to create the file, in windows installations there is a neo4j-community.vmoptions file in the bin directory.

Comment: A follow up: Neo4J ships with a 32bit JRE for windows. I downloaded a 64bit JRE and use a symbolic link from the NEO4J JRE to the 64bit JRE. Neo4J fails to start with the error 'The JVM found at ..\jre is damaged. Please reinstall or define EXE4J_JAVA_HOME to point to an installed 32-bit JDK or JRE'. It seems that NEO4J only works with 32-bit, and that limits memory to 1.4G

Comment: I just pinged on that chat you created yesterday

Comment: So, is there really no way around the 1.4G limit on Windows? If anyone can confirm it I'd appreciate that, so I can move on to some alternative solution (OrientDB maybe).

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround in Windows, I've been launching it as follows in command prompt
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Neo4j Community\bin\neo4j-desktop-2.2.0.jar" -d64 -Xmx400g ...